# Upload image in binary using Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, alamofire

I'm trying to upload an image from my view in SwiftUI.

In my post api I am having to upload the image with cid and it's extension i.e.

```
registerSelfieApi(url: "https://contributorapi.yogpathwellness.com/ProfileMaster/ImageUploadInBinary?Cid=\(cid)&Ext=HEIC", img: selectedImage!, param: nil)
```

I'm using the following functions:

```
func uploadImage(Url: String,image: UIImage, imageName: String, methodType: HTTPMethod, headers: HTTPHeaders?, completion: @escaping (String?)->Void) {
    
    Alamofire.upload(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!, to: URL(string: Url)!, method: .post, headers: headers).responseString { response in
        if let response = response.result.value {
            completion(response)
            print("resposne is \(response)")
        } else {
            completion("response not in string: \(response)")
        }
    }
}
```

And calling it using:

```
    func registerSelfieApi(url: String, img: UIImage, param: [String: Any]?) {
        
        isLoading = true
        NetworkManager.shared.uploadImage(Url: url, image: img, imageName: "file", methodType: .post, headers: ["Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"]) { response in
            isLoading = false
            if response?.isEmpty == false {
                docPanCardShow = true
                print(response)
//                alertMessage = "file Not uploaded"
//                showsAlert = true
            } else {
                print("no response")
                if fromStatus == true {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } else {
                    docPanCardShow = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm allowing the user to upload image from the gallery:

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Button("Selfie") {
                        self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                        self.isImagePickerDisplay.toggle()

                    }
                    .font(Font.custom(FontName.normal, size: 17))
                    .frame(width: percentWidth(percentage: 35), height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color(orangeColor))
                    .tint(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Button("NEXT") {
                        //jpeg, png
                        print("\(lastPathUrl)  lastpath")
                        if let cid = cid, selectedImage != nil {
                            registerSelfieApi(url: "https://contributorapi.yogpathwellness.com/ProfileMaster/ImageUploadInBinary?Cid=\(cid)&Ext=HEIC", img: selectedImage!, param: nil)

                        } else {
                            print("this is else statement")
                            if fromStatus == true {
                                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            } else {
                                docPanCardShow = true
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .font(Font.custom(FontName.normal, size: 17))
                    .frame(width: percentWidth(percentage: 35), height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color(orangeColor))
                    .tint(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
                    
                }
```

It should upload the image but somehow it is not working. It doesn't throw any error. And my console prints `no response` and in the next line it prints `resposne is`
I am just mentioning as it is how the if conditions are executed I am not sure if it helps.
This is what I am getting from postman after I upload any image selected from phone or simulator:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/yogpath_vendor_data/vid_357/Pro_22082717591959.HEIC
```

I am not sure what the above url conveys but I am just mentioning things here. it's my first time uploading an image.
my question is what am I missing? and how do I upload the image using it.

Comment: Could your `print(response)` in `if let response = response.result.value`?

Comment: I have used the same in my function i.e.
Alamofire.upload(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!, to: URL(string: Url)!, method: .post, headers: headers).responseString { response in
        if let response = response.result.value {
            completion(response)
            print("resposne is \(response)")
        } else {
            completion("response not in string: \(response)")
        }
was that what you were asking?

Comment: The `response` in the Alamofire Call. You don't even check for validity of the reponse (basic one be it's a 200 HTTP response), you could have receive a 401, 403, etc. for instance...

Comment: that's right. but I have checked the response from postman and it's 200 http response. I don't think that shall create an issue at least for now. I'm stuck with uploading it in binary.

Comment: But what's the response print in your Alamofire code? It's not because it's works with Potman, that your code is identical!

Comment: I am not able to understand why it doesn't print anything in response part when I try to print it using "print("response is \(response)")" and it prints "response is". 
my guess is at least it shall print something like "response is 234 bytes" . What am I missing?

Comment: Since you use `responseString`, it's type is a `String`; In this case, it's an empty String, so it's `""`. You need to print `response`, the parameter of the closure, not the local variable you created with `if let`. Add `print("Alamofire reponse: \(response)")` BEFORE the `if let`...

Comment: getting it! did the same
 it prints "Alamofire reponse: SUCCESS:"

Comment: Maybe print `response.response` to get the HTTPURLResponse?

Comment: got something like:
response is Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600002ff6e60> { URL: https://contributorapi.yogpathwellness.com/ProfileMaster/ImageUploadInBinary?Cid=VID_357&Ext=HEIC } { Status Code: 404, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        private

Comment: So you get a 404 error... Is the URL correct? Is it missing some parameters, values?

Comment: It is missing two parameters namely "token" and "DeviceId"

Comment: I guess they need to be put inside the headers, so add them?

Comment: I added the tokens using:
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Token": "VXJCQkZxVGk5cTNROGhSUk1FRlFTNHUvbzVVYkJjOGhWTSthaWlWc280QT0jMTIzNDU2Nzg=",
            "DeviceId": "12345678"
        ]
and it's uploaded and works perfect.

Comment: however I have to add tokens using something like
let header = ["token": (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: User_Defaults.token) as? String ?? ""), "DeviceId": (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: User_Defaults.fbToken) as? String ?? "")]

this shall work but isn't working. when I do print(header) in this case, it prints:
*on next comment

Comment: ["token": "SUhKMG1xWWo1MjIxd1Z1UG4vcTVkcThWdTJKMXM2dmVERGY5WVZDcHNSST0jY3hBSGMtanJnRTItcDlFWUNWbnV1bTpBUEE5MWJINjQ2LW1QZXFTNXlXVVhIQ2ROZjlNOUNvc0xxalpqbUFvQnJSbGRaM1RwdUg2VzdIek1qcFZIdUVXT0JtWjNRbzBMUmNlalFXbkcxNm1hLXZrbXdfUjczZDZLNVdaZEhoRWtOTzgzMnl0dzUtbm5YdFhDZUlvdUNsOEF0dVhKYkd2TWo5Sg==", "DeviceId": "cxAHc-jrgE2-p9EYCVnuum:APA91bH646-mPeqS5yWUXHCdNf9M9CosLqjZjmAoBrRldZ3TpuH6W7HzMjpVHuEWOBmZ3Qo0LRcejQWnG16ma-vkmw_R73d6K5WZdHhEkNO832ytw5-nnXtXCeIouCl8AtuXJbGvMj9J"]

Comment: I don't know from where it generated this kind of token